# Which theme attribute changes the text color of an EditText's error message

Tags: android, themes, android-edittext, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my form I use `setError("")` on an `EditText` field. My Application-Theme extends `android:Theme.Holo`.
I have manually set an image with a dark background for `android:errorMessageBackground` and `android:errorMessageBackgroundAbove`.

And now here's the problem: The text color of the error message is also very dark and not readable.

I tried changing different `textColor` attributes in my Theme, but I wasn't able to find the correct one.

May anyone could help me, please?
Thank you!
Chris

Comment: Ok I found out a solution. I actually couldn't find the specific theme attribute, wich needs to be extended. 

But one can set <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ffffffff</item> to the color nedded. That did the trick for me. 
This is not colliding with other colors in my application, because I set the text colors for every kind of element in its own style set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: [This](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10378&q=setError&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) answer should help you to resolve the issue

Comment: Could you tell me how did you manage to set the background using errorMessageBackground?

I've set minSDK to 7 and target to 16 and I'm not able to use this attribute in my theme, but all I get is: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'errorMessageBackground'.

My question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127710/change-color-of-edittexts-error-message?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text color by using **HTML Font Tag.**

But for customizing background color, you should make your own custom pop up.
For more information, Kindly go through this link:- 
[How to write style to error text of EditText in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413575/how-to-write-style-to-error-text-of-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
editText.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Error Message!</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

do following in manifest.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="LightErrorFix" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
         <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/secondary_text_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the property
`android:textColorPrimaryInverse="YourCOLOR"` to the color nedded.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did sth like this:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
```

you can do the following:

```
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

or

```
text.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
```

or if you want/need alpha:

```
text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
```

Anyhow, you should specify your colors in your color.xml (wayyy better to be maintained):

```
<color name="myColor">#f00</color>
```

and then use it like this:

```
text.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myColor));
```

Have fun :)

Comment: Won't this change the colour of the EditText and not the error popover?

Answer (score 0):

My response works, is in kotlin.

```
private fun setErrorOnSearchView(searchView: SearchView, errorMessage: String) {
    val id = searchView.context
            .resources
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
    val editText = searchView.find<EditText>(id)

    val errorColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.red)
    val fgcspan = ForegroundColorSpan(errorColor)
    val builder = SpannableStringBuilder(errorMessage)
    builder.setSpan(fgcspan, 0, errorMessage.length, 0)
    editText.error = builder
}
```