# Wrong background images in EditText.setError(..) popup

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

I'm using `EditText.setError(..)` to show up an error message if the user did not correctly fill in the formular. 
The app will be for Honeycomb. I tried with both `android:style/Theme.Holo` and `android:style/Theme.Holo.Light`.

The Problem is that the background images of the error popup seem to be wrong. There are to images for that background - one, for when the error popup is shown above the EditText and one for when it's shown beneath it. In `Theme.Holo` the above-image has a black background and the beneath-image has a white background. The text color always is black, so the text is not readable in the above-popup.

Before updating to the latest sdk I was able to "hack" this problem with the following lines of code:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ffffffff</item>
<item name="android:errorMessageBackground">@drawable/popup_inline_error</item>
<item name="android:errorMessageAboveBackground">@drawable/popup_inline_error_above</item>
```

But now with sdk tools 12 I get a compilation error using these lines with the information that e.g. the resource `android:errorMessageBackground` could not be found...

Any ideas? Thank you! 
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745577/which-theme-attribute-changes-the-text-color-of-an-edittexts-error-message) thread has a solution for this.

The problem also seems to be fixed since Android 4.0.